# Updating symbol size units from mm to map units in rule-based symbology in QGIS

Tags: qgis, symbology, style, rule-based, map-unit

I have a quite complex rule-based symbology that is currently using millimetres as size units.

[image: rule-based symbology]

All third levels look the same, they just have different parents.

Is there a way to change symbol size units from millimetres to map units for every rule entry so I don't have to click each entry and switch (which would be a pain in the * for a few dozen entries)?

When I have a categorized approach, I have the general symbology, that I can easily change and then applies to all categories, but how do I achieve that with a rule-based symbology?

The same goes for other aspects, like symbol size. Can I change that size for all symbols at once? e. g. from 15 mu to 18 mu.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the following script in [QGIS Code Editor](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/python_console.html#the-code-editor). It also works on nested rules. Select the layer before running the script.

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer()
renderer = layer.renderer().clone()

def set_output_unit(rules):
    for rule in rules.children():
        rule.symbol().setOutputUnit(1) # 1: MapUnits    
        if rule.children():
            set_output_unit(rule)

rules = renderer.rootRule()
set_output_unit(rules)

layer.setRenderer(renderer)
layer.triggerRepaint()
```

[image]

Comment: I am on my rulebased layer. could it have anything to do with nested styles and the parents not having any symbology on their own?

Comment: It could be. Could you share a screenshot on how the rule-based symbology looks like?

Comment: I added a picture. As you can see, two symbols I have manually changed to map units, the others didn't

Comment: Ok. I've edited the answer. Now, it works on nested rules.

Answer (score 9):

Quick and dirty would be:

- export Style as `*.qml`
- open it in Notepad++ for example
- search for: `<Option value="MM" type="QString" name="line_width_unit"/>`
- replace with: `<Option value="MapUnit" type="QString" name="line_width_unit"/>`
- import your style again